# Let's go on a fun and magical journey of disputing a review audit!

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Well, [here](//stackoverflow.com/review/close/15317039) is what I'm disputing. I clicked "Close", it said I failed, etc.

Let's check our Red Flag List™:

1. Six varying answers.
2. The first sentence of [the top answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/42212876/6388243) is:

   > Let's see how many different (but equivalent) solutions we can collect here.
3. [The first answer after that](//stackoverflow.com/a/42213091/6388243) starts with:

   > BTW, I found another solution
4. The essential question of the question is "how do I convert [type] to [other-type-that-can't-be-casted-to]?" There are multiple ways to go about doing this.

This makes it a very good case for being Too Broad—which was what I tried to close as.

So:

- Let's get this question closed. Or alternatively, give me an explanation of why I was wrong about this.
- <s>I'd appreciate it if a ♦ moderator could remove this from my audit history.</s> It seems that this isn't something mods can do. Oh freakin' well.

Comment: I really don't understand how you would find that question off-topic.

Comment: Wait...if you were looking at the answers, doesn't that mean you opened the actual question post in a new tab/window? You would have been able to see the questions votes at that point. The question having a high score and nothing but up votes means its an audit.

Comment: While the "Too Broad" close reason includes *"There are either too many possible answers..."* I think the emphasis should be on *"... or good answers would be too long for this format."* As long as the answers can be relatively concise I don't see any problem if there are multiple possible ways of achieving the desired goal. Especially when it comes to Java 8 streams there are almost always a couple of different ways of providing a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not seeing how your red flag criterion make this question "Too Broad", specifically given that, during a review, you're meant to be looking objectively at the *question* and not its accompanying answers.

That said, this makes your last bullet point relevant:

> The essential question of the question is "how do I convert [type] to [other-type-that-can't-be-casted-to]?" There are multiple ways to go about doing this.

It could *easily* be the case that the OP didn't realize that `OptionalDouble` is preferable to `Optional<Double>` because of their familiarity of working with `Optional<T>` instead of any of the more concrete `Optional` types.  While yes, the answers want to suggest this more as a way to convert foo into bar, even *that* as a question isn't automatically too broad.

In my mind:

- The question states its purpose clearly.
- The question has an end goal in mind - convert from `OptionalDouble` to `Optional<Double>`.
- There are a handful (and really a handful) of clear and concise paths to accomplish this.
- An appropriate answer is to suggest that one *not* do this instead.

None of this seems overly broad to me.

If you disagree with the text of the first answer for whatever reason, you can safely remove that as noise.  I should have already done so by the time you get to read this answer; I'd encourage you to make other edits to clean up the quality of the answers, too.

Comment: *"you're meant to be looking objectively at the question and not its accompanying answers."* Got a citation for that?

Comment: @StephenLeppik:  [Everything that exists](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) on the subject of [reviewing questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) only ever explicitly calls out *questions*, and not answers.  I won't deny that looking at answers can help you determine the aftermath of the question - that is, if these answers really were going about the "Too Broad" path - but that likely stems from a question which is still on-topic but could be edited to be made clearer.

Comment: In addition to this, in the review window, you're only shown *the question*.  If you can't arrive at a conclusion of whether or not to keep the question open based on the question alone, then there's no shame in skipping the review.

Comment: I suppose I *have* been throwing around "Too Broad" a bit much lately.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Too Broad is most likely the most abused close reason that we have currently. When I feel like answering a few questions, I often navigate to the close vote queue and review under the filter "[javascript] too broad" and i find plenty of on-topic answerable questions.